# Get mediaWiki Error: Class "MWStake\MediaWiki\Component\ProcessManager\ProcessManager" not found

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have installed mediaWiki with version 1.39 LTS together with the extension "Page Forms" and the "Cognitive Process Designer".

The wiki of the Cognitive Process Designer says that you should enter this command in the terminal for the background service:

```
php extensions/CognitiveProcessDesigner/vendor/mwstake/mediawiki-component-processmanager/maintenance/processRunner.php maintenance/Maintenance.php --wait
```

Unfortunately, I get the following errors when I do this:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/CognitiveProcessDesigner/vendor/mwstake/mediawiki-component-processmanager/maintenance/processRunner.php maintenance/Maintenance.php --wait
[f84ac3ccf60395c0b4824c20] [no req]   Error: Class "MWStake\MediaWiki\Component\ProcessManager\ProcessManager" not found
Backtrace:
from /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/CognitiveProcessDesigner/vendor/mwstake/mediawiki-component-processmanager/maintenance/processRunner.php(31)
#0 /var/www/html/mediawiki/maintenance/includes/MaintenanceRunner.php(309): ProcessRunner->execute()
#1 /var/www/html/mediawiki/maintenance/doMaintenance.php(85): MediaWiki\Maintenance\MaintenanceRunner->run()
#2 /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/CognitiveProcessDesigner/vendor/mwstake/mediawiki-component-processmanager/maintenance/processRunner.php(157): require_once(string)
#3 {main}
```

I have called the given command. I expect the background service to start.

Comment: maybe you have to run composer update in the directory of the process designer extension